# Query builder не принимает запрос

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

Всем добрый день! НЕ принимается вот такой запрос, как я его не крутил и какие только варианты не использовал. При чём, проблема в первой части запроса, так как вторая по отдельности - выполняется:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM RealState_RiskEngine.Tables                                                
WHERE table_name LIKE 'accountTest') DROP TABLE accountTest 

CREATE TABLE accountTest(idAccountHierarchy nchar(100) NOT NULL, ItemName nchar(100), HierarchyLevel int)
```

Вот что выдаёт query builder: The DROP TABLE SQL construct or statement is not supported.

И вот это:[image: Описание ошибки]

А вот структура сервера и бд:

1. имя сервера
2. Папка Databases
3. RealState_RiskEngine
4. Папка Tables
5. собственно таблицы с именами dbo.TableName

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А если так?

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM  information_schema.tables
WHERE table_name = 'accountTest') DROP TABLE accountTest
```

Comment: WTF?! КАК?! Я после Постгриса и Мускула был в шоке, увидев "1", а теперь еще и information_schema какая то...Магия :) 

Спасибо большое!

Comment: "1" здесь совершенно не при чем. Вы можете использовать любое выражение, поскольку проверяется наличие строк - EXISTS.